# joomla admin template not loading, how do i change it manually?

Tags: templates, admin

Hi joomla's defaut admin template "system" is not loading css stylesheets, so i wonder if there is a way to change the admin template from phpmyadmin.

Want to use the other template kephri

Answer (score 4):

For Changing template from phpmyadmin

==> find table #_template_styles.

==> set "home"="0" for current back-end template.

==> set "home"="1" for the template you want to make default for back-end.

Just care about client id, it is always 1 for back-end templates.

Comment: I forgot to mention that i´m working with Joomla 1.5

Comment: find the table #_templates_menu and remove all entries which have client_id=1

and then insert a new row ( template ==> khepri) ( menuid ==> 0 ) ( client_id ==> 1)

Note : Remember to backup this table.

Comment: This answer was helpful to me. I'm running J!3.x

Answer (score -1):

I have Joomla 3.8.7. You can setup Backend Template from User > Manage . Select your user, go to "Basic Settings" tab and select your backend template style from the dropdown list.